# Bibliography entries - Address and Location use/misuse

Tags: bibliographies

I see some .bib entries that use `location` other use `address`, are those the same? Are those excluding? Conflicting? An updated version? Or completely different things?

What should normally fit in this fields? The conference location? The publisher address? Author address?